# Visual Studio RDLC act different on local and server

Tags: asp.net, server, localhost, rdlc, currency-formatting

I am using RDLC for reporting, and its own functions such as;

```
=SUM(CDbl(Fields!iletisimOiv.Value))
```

here is the result for localhost, working perfect;

[image]

But when I publish it to server, here is what I get ;

[image]

Those numbers are currency and bottom row (bold) is their total.I guess its due server. I double check rdlc properties and server's culture settings but still no progress. How can I fix that.(I tried it on different local machines, it works normally in localhosts)

Comment: You may need to expressly format your numbers to eliminate how "culture" of the server affects report formatting.

Comment: @InitK Thanks for response, Can it be matter of report dll in bin folder ?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean as I don't know how your project is structured. Did you apply any "Number" formatting on any of the fields to test this?

Comment: Yea still no progress

Comment: Maybe you have formatted your sum field as a percentage setting TextBox.Format as something like "p" or "p2" and this working differently on two machine. You can force formatting as currency setting TextBox.Format as "c" (i.e. "c2").